# Ubuntu to windows 7 share cifs mount going dormant

Tags: 14.04, mount, windows-7, fstab, cifs

I have an ubuntu 14.04 installation and I have a windows 7 pc with a hand full of share mount points.. 
The mounts work great if I am constantly using them, However if I let them sit for a little while they will go dormant.. If I try to cd into the mounted dir or do an ls or even a df  it will just sit there untill I reboot.. If i unmount them then remount them prior to accessing them they will come up and be ok.. Is this an issue on windows7 or is it something on my ubutnu box's end??

I am using fstab to mount them like this..

```
//192.168.11.50/win_clone /win_clone cifs  username=winuser,password=winuserpw,sec=ntlm,vers=2.1  0  0
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did multiple reboots and remounts on both systems and have not had any issues since.. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

if it works after a sudo mount -a, may be check this :
/etc/default/rcS and add this ASYNCMOUNTNFS=no

good luck